# Is it possible to add additional input to a later step of an mrjob?

Tags: emr, mrjob

I have an mrjob that consists of 3 steps.
The second step expects as input the results of the first step plus some more content from S3.

I understand that I can always "stream" it through the first step, meaning emit is as is, and only use it in the second step, but I would like to avoid this.

Is there a way to define additional input to later steps in mrjob?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping the steps into a single job, you might consider using a persistent job flow to separate your task into the parts before and after the secondary input:

[Re-use Amazon Elastic MapReduce instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880283/re-use-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-instance)

http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/emr-advanced.html